# Why is my fetch request method GET instead of POST?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

```
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [birthday, setBirthday] = useState('')
  const [age, setAge] = useState('')


  function handleClick(e){
   
    const newFriend = {
      name: name,
      birthday: birthday,
      age: age,
    }
    console.log(newFriend)

    props.addNewFriend(newFriend)
  }



  return (
    <div>
      <form id='friendform'>       
        <input type='text' placeholder='name' name='name' id='name' onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
        <input type='date' placeholder='birthday' name='birthday' id='birthday' onChange={(e) => setBirthday(e.target.value)} />
        <input type='text' placeholder='age' name='age' id='age' onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)} />
        <input type='submit' value='submit' onClick={handleClick}  />
        
      </form>
    </div>
  )
```

```
  const addNewFriend = async (friend) => {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(FRIEND_END, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(friend),
      });
      if (resp.ok) {
        const data = await resp.json();
        setData([...data, data]); // Update the local data state with the new friend from the API
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('addNewFriend had an error:', e);
    }
  };
```

it was working perfectly until I added the age:age,  age and age,setAge.

When I checked the network app it says it's a get and have no idea why. It's not an issue with javascript being enabled but it's an issue with the api call but I can't figure out where it went wrong. If you want the full code I have it available at https://github.com/ProfessorSocks/week-16-new/tree/main/final-project

At first I tried all the usual suspects before i realized it was an api call error. (javascript is enabled, homepage and poxy did nothing, and serve doesn't work on my computer). So then I went over my code but i couldn't find any reason why it would giving me a get instead of a post.

Comment: You've got a "submit" button in a `<form>`. If you don't block the default action, which according to the posted code you aren't, then after your handlers the browser will submit the form. Because your `<form>` tag doesn't have a "method" attribute, the default is "GET".

Comment: Your `<button>` handler `onClick={handleClick}` needs to be moved to the `<form>` as an `onSubmit={handleSubmit}` and you need to call `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: [Worth to know] to update a state depending on its previous value, it is better to pass callback to setState function. Like so `setData(prev => [...prev, data])`